# 4 by 4 bit Multiplier. Logisim help

Tags: circuit-design, logisim

I am trying to recreate the following design:

[image: Test image]

When I create it in Logisim, this is the error I get:

[image: circuit]

I understand the incompability is due to the number of data bits. When I adjust the data bits, none of the output will work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a splitter component (first item under "Wiring") when combining multiple 1-bit signals into a bus, or when separating them back out. Simply wiring them together, like you've done, doesn't work.

Here's what it should look like:

[image]

Note that you'll need to split and recombine the output from each of the adders -- for instance, the input to the second adder is made up of `{CO, S3, S2, S1}`, not `{S3, S2, S1, S0}`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this 4-bit unsigned it's really working

[image: 4bit unsigned]